# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'

Tags: python

I am getting error while trying to do below,

```
df1.loc[~mask & ~mask1, 'diff'] = (df1.loc[~mask & ~mask1, 'MATURITY_DATE'] - effdt)/timedelta(days=365)
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'.
```

The above code work in python-3.8 but not in 3.11.4, can someone suggest what needs to be done to make it work in 3.11.4 ?

Comment: This is not a [mre]. Please add the assignment for `df1`, `mask`, `mask1` and `effdt`, and the complete traceback to the question.